# Coffeescript classes variable fields - keeping initialization clean

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have some elementary object classes in my program. They have both functions and data fields in them. I just realized that if I declare some default data fields values outside the `construct` method then they will not get reset on `object = new Class params` kind of initialization.

```
class Book extends DBNode

  language: 'en'
  title: ''
  year: 0

  # function
  bookReaded: (callback)->

    # db stuff
    callback()
```

ie: in this case creating a new Book obj and then editing its title will result in the following instances being initialized with the title field already set to the value of the last instance.

```
class Book extends DBNode

  constructor: ->

    @language: 'en'
    @title: ''
    @year: 0
    super(props, user, cb)

  # function
  bookReaded: (callback)->

    # db stuff
    callback()
```

Whereas in this case fields get properly reset each time and the title field will be set to blank at each initialization.

Well - you will say - obviously: they are prototypes. You will say. And I get that... now.

Anyhow, the matter is still a little bit fuzzy for me, so I wanted to ask if just declaring all variable fields in the constructor is enough to provide all cross-instance security needed  or if there are some other things that should be kept in mind when dealing with prototypes instead of simple objects.

As I'm using it server side, my main concern is about the simultaneous execution of stuff that could mess up this kind of global-scope situation, and whether I should consider using only normal objects (I do make use of inheritance advantages in some functions, but nothing that cannot be achieved with a couple of extra lines of code)...

Comment: What do you mean by "reset"? Is that supposed to be a lowercase `new`? Could you maybe post some example code?

Comment: thank you, I provided a code sample as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is just declaring all variable fields in the constructor enough to provide all cross-instance security needed

It's not about security, it's about functionality. But yes, if you assign all mutable properties in the constructor then you are on the safe side (for the primitive values in your example it actually doesn't make a difference).

> As I'm using it server side, my main concern is about the simultaneous execution of stuff

There is no simultaneous execution of code in JavaScript. Not even on the server side.

> Should I consider using only normal objects (I do make use of inheritance advantages in some functions, but nothing that cannot be achieved with a couple of extra lines of code)...

No. The point of inheritance is to save those lines of code. Also, by putting methods on the prototype you increase performance of your code.

Comment: I meant threaded sorry. Thanks for the answer! One last clarification: so what happens with prototypes is that new ones will be clones of the last one, but old ones will keep their properties even thou the global prototype may change after their initialization (for example after callbacks or whatnot)?

Comment: No. Everytime you create a `new Class` object, it will inherit from the same (single) `Class.prototype` object. And that one usually never changes - only the instances do.